# UIView, struggling with some basics ( xcode, iOS )

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview

I'm struggling with some basics in my storyboard-based iOS Application.

I like to load some UIView's which are builded up in NIB-Files (xib). If I load the View, the `initWithCoder`-method will be called.

Now I like to load "green" Views; I read, that I'm able to put some other initializations in the `initWithCoder` - but only "new" objects and nothing, that regarding the View itself, like self.backgroundColor in cause of memory (maybe the object isn't complete initialized at that point).

Where is the best place to add some stuff, like `setBackgroundColor`, `setCornerRadius` in the view-Class itself?

Comment: No :-) I'm using UIView and not UIViewController. There isn't a viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear etc in UIView's class.

Comment: @Thomas `initWithCoder:` or `initWithFrame:` **should work fine.** If it doesn't you certainly screwed up something - I'd suggest you create a blank project for testing it. You can also *create all this programmatically* and completely avoid using Interface Builder.

Comment: yeah, it works fine. I ran into missunderstanding during talk about bad practise...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm doing it like this:

```
NSArray* nibViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCustomView" owner:nil options:nil];
self = [nibViews objectAtIndex: 0]; //here it would be best practice to loop through nibViews and get the first view that is member of your class.
```

Also , the view , in the nib file is set as a `MyCustomView` instead of `UIView`.
After these 2 lines you can set any values that you want. Be aware though , if you set the frame for super for example , it will be overwritten by the values in the xib file. So better set everything AFTER loading the nib , not before.

As far as I know , there are no callbacks for `UIView` loading as `viewDidLoad` is for `UIViewController`.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

EDIT:

You can do something like this:

```
- (id)initWithInfo:(MyInfoClass *) selectedInfo Body:(NSString *) _body
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
         NSArray* nibViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCustomClass" owner:nil options:nil];
         self = [nibViews objectAtIndex: 0];

         [self setInfo:selectedInfo];
         [self setBody:_body];
    }
}
```

And then just use that `initWithInfo: Body:` method.

Comment: Yes, I loading the view exactly your way.
But, I like to set the Color inside the class and not outside ( and i will be outside, if I set the Color after the two lines of code...)

Comment: Check my edited answer. I hope I understood your question correctly.